# Error tokenizing data while uploading CSV file into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, out-of-memory

I have an 8GB CSV file that contains information about companies created in France. 
When I try to upload it in Python using pandas.read_csv, I get various types of error; I believe it’s a combination of 3 factors that cause the problem:

- The size of the file (8GB)
- The French characters in the cells (like “é”)
- The fact that this CSV file is organized like an Excel file; the fields are separated by column, just like an XLS file

When I tried to import the file using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\..\data.csv')
```

I got the following error: **OSError: Initializing from file failed**

Then, to eliminate the problem about the size, I copy the file (data.csv) and paste it, only keeping the first 25 rows (data2.csv). This is a much lighter file, to eliminate the size problem:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\..\data2.csv')
```

I get the same **OSError: Initializing from file failed** error.

After some research, I try the following code with **Data2.csv**

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\..\data2.csv', sep="\t", encoding="latin")
```

This time, the import successfully works, but in a weird format, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUBQn.jpg. All fields are in the same column.

So this even with the size problem eliminated, it doesn't properly read the csv file. And still, I need to work with the main file, Data.csv. So I try the same code on the initial file (data.csv):

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\..\data.csv', sep="\t", encoding="latin")
```

I get: **ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory**

What is the proper code to read this data.csv properly?

Thank you,

Comment: Can you add the first few lines of your CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

From your image it looks like the file is separated by semi-colons (;). Try using ";" as the sep in the read_csv function.

Pandas reads the csv into ram - an 8GB file could easily exhaust this - try reading the file in chunks. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas)